# Como atualizar a pagina e executar uma função javascript

Tags: javascript

Quero que quando a pagina seja atualizada execute uma função ao abrir 
            Ao executar esse reload abrir a pagina com o próximo codigo:

```
       ---------------Executou para dar reload------------
    window.location.href = '2.php';
       ---------------Executar ao abrir---------------
        var mostrarProdutos = function(){
            $('div.loader').show();
            $('div.loaderww').hide();
        }
```

Comment: coloquei o primeiro codigo errado não é  window.location.mostrarProdutos("2.php");

Comment: window.location.href = '2.php';

Comment: João, você pode clicar em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/297643/edit) para fazer essa alteração.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, primeiro aconselho você utilizar o método [`window.location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) para recarregar a página atual. Depois, você pode usar o [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) para gravar uma variável na sessão atual do usuário, assim:

```
// execute essa função para atualizar a página
function recarregarPagina() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("recarregou", "true"); // antes de atualizar, você seta uma variável no sessionStorage como true
    window.location.reload(); // atualiza a página
}
```

Ao carregar a página, você realiza a verificação se a página foi atualizada:

```
// aqui você recupera a variável que você setou (ou não) na sessionStorage
var recarregou = sessionStorage.getItem("recarregou");

// verifica que a página foi atualizada
if (recarregou) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("recarregou"); // remove a variável
    mostrarProdutos(); // executa sua função
}
```

Adaptado de [Refresh page and run function after JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904975/refresh-page-and-run-function-after-javascript).